# Finding only required links on a webpage using xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, contains

I have a webpage that has more than hundred links on a webpage. I am trying to see if i can only store the required number of web links and store them in a array and run a loop for verifying data within each individual links.

The number of links are dynamic and change as per the user, so each time the page loads it has to find the specified links.

This is what i currently have under the for loop for each user:

```
List<WebElement> linksize = driver.findElements(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("totalbookings"))); 
int linksCount = linksize.size();
String[] linksENR = null;
linksENR = new String[linksCount];
System.out.println(linksCount);
if (linksCount > 0)
{
System.out.println("We have enrollment");
System.out.println(linksCount);
for (int i = 1; i <= linksCount; i++)
{
driver.navigate().to(linksENR[i]);
System.out.println("here");
}
}
else
{
System.out.println("No enrollment record found");
}
```

The xpath for the elements that i am trying to click for user 1 is and there is one element:

```
.//*[@id='006g0000007RH1V_00Nb0000009Yc1K_body']/table/tbody/tr[2]/th/a
```

The xpath for the elements that i am trying to click for user 2 is as follows and there are two elements:

```
.//*[@id='006g0000007RH1V_00Nb0000009Yc1K_body']/table/tbody/tr[2]/th/a
.//*[@id='006g0000007RH1V_00Nb0000009Yc1K_body']/table/tbody/tr[3]/th/a
```

This is what i am using to search with the xpath:

```
totalbookings = .//*[contains(@id, "7RH1V_00Nb0000009Yc1K_body") and contains(@tagName , "a")]
```

Output:

```
 No enrollment record found
```

Is there way to uniquely identify only few chosen links with the xpath? Please assist.

Here is the HTML information for the element:

```
     <table class="list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr class="headerRow"></tr>
    <!--

     ListRow 

    -->
    <tr class="dataRow even first" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}">
        <td class="actionColumn"></td>
        <th class=" dataCell " scope="row">
            <a class=" firepath-matching-node" href="/a1Bg0000001ih6M"></a>
        </th>
        <td class=" dataCell CurrencyElement"></td>
        <td class=" dataCell "></td>
        <td class=" dataCell "></td>
        <td class=" dataCell "></td>
        <td class=" dataCell numericalColumn"></td>
        <td class=" dataCell "></td>
    </tr>
    <!--

     ListRow 

    -->
    <tr class="dataRow odd last" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}"></tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing your HTML. What is `@tagName`? It appears in your XPath expression but isn't otherwise mentioned in the question. You might try this XPath: `.//*[contains(@id, "7RH1V_00Nb0000009Yc1K_body")]/table/tbody/tr/th/a`

Comment: Post relevant portion of your HTML

Comment: @LarsH thank you for the comment. Here is the Html information

Answer (score 0):

I would do it more like this:

```
List<WebElement> pl = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@id,'totalbookings')]")); 
if (pl.size() > 0)
{
  System.out.println("We have enrollment. Looping through links...");
  for ( WebElement we : pl )
  {
    we.click();
    System.out.println("Clicked link: " + we.toString() );
    thisPageObject.verifyPageLoaded();
    driver.executeScript("window.history.go(-1)");
    org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.Sleeper.sleepTight(1000);
  }
} else {}
  System.out.println("No enrollment record found");
}
```

Comment: @djandogan the issue seems to be coming from that the element is not getting located using the xpath in "totalbookings" but the rest of code definately helps one's it finds the element i am lookng for. Thank you.

Comment: Well, ya, the Xpath I provided can certainly be adjusted to work for your use.  I would use Firefox Firepath to test your xpath locators.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `contains(@tagName , "a")` is intended to mean that the current element has a descendent element `a`. But it *actually* means that the current element has an *attribute* named `tagName`, and this attribute's *string value* contains the letter "a".

This says to me that you are trying to do something moderately complex with a tool that you really know little about. There's no shame in not knowing XPath, but a few hours spent learning the fundamentals will spare you many hours of trial and error and trying to communicate your problem on web forums.

To do what I think you intended to do, you can use the following XPath expression:

```
.//*[contains(@id, "7RH1V_00Nb0000009Yc1K_body")]//a
```

That is if you're trying to select the links themselves. If you're trying to select the element whose `id` you're testing, as your `totalbookings` XPath expression implies, you could do

```
.//*[contains(@id, "7RH1V_00Nb0000009Yc1K_body") and .//a]
```

but that would not select the links, which was your stated goal.

Also, both of the above look for descendants of the current element (whatever that is). With `driver.findElements()` you don't seem to have a current node, so it would make more sense to remove the `.` from the beginning of the XPath and just use `//*`... to make it clear that you're looking for nodes anywhere in the web page, not just in some chosen subtree.

Comment: Larsh thanks for the response and explanation, however neither of the solution worked. The element is still not found, by using the xpath suggestions provided. I am still getting "No enrollment record found" and yes you are right, the end goal is to click on the link. I was under the impression that all the links on the webpage has a tag name attribute and "a" is present.

Comment: In the HTML you showed us, there's no `tagName` attribute. But you haven't shown us the element whose ID is '006g0000007RH1V_00Nb0000009Yc1K_body'. I'm not sure why you're getting no results for your XPath. Again, showing us more HTML (the parent element of `<table>`) might help. Did you try removing the `.` at the beginning of the XPath expression, as suggested in the last paragraph of my answer?

Comment: neither your solution worked and honestly your attitude stinks for people who are here to learn and get solutions, you can take your answers and shove it where the sun don't shine.

Comment: @YawellIt'sallgood: Ouch. I was just asking clarifying questions so that we'd be able to help you better. Not sure what you interpreted as a negative attitude, but if you'd like to tell me, I'll keep it in mind. From my point of view, you've asked for donated time to help you with your problem. The information you've supplied has some gaps and inconsistencies. Until those are resolved, I can't make enough sense of the problem to help more than I have. If you're here to learn, please answer the questions I asked. I'm willing to help you find a solution if you're willing to engage.